# Div in facebook app outside ssl for chrome only

Tags: jquery, facebook, ssl

I am using http://pagescroller.com/ code in an Facebook app. It works perfect in all browsers except chrome and only when online on facebook tab, where the navigation div (menu) is not shown. I think that is why the div that produces the menu is generated through a js file and chrome considers it outside ssl.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initiate page scroller plugin
    $('#wrapper').pageScroller({
        navigationClass: 'iconNav light'
    });         
}); 
</script>
```

Could it be the error? Ofline as an html it works perfect. Uploaded as part of a facebook app it seems that facebook ignores the script but why only in chrome? I have tested it in many ways but still the same.

Any other way to pass this code? Have you ever experienced any similar problems with chrome and facebook apps?

Comment: It seems that there is no solution to this. I used another scroll plugin. For anyone facing the same problem.